# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure' in Airflow v2.3.3

Tags: azure, airflow, azure-blob-storage

**Description**

Airflow `v2.3.3` and Python `v3.9.13`

When accessing the `azure-storage-blob` library through Airflow it throws the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

**Reproduce**

1. Create a new virtual environment
2. Install Airflow using `pip install apache-airflow==2.3.3`
3. Install Airflow Providers for Azure `apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure==4.1.0`
4. Call using `from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient`

**Additional Context**

Output of `pip freeze`

```
apache-airflow                           2.3.3
apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-azure 4.1.0
azure-batch                              12.0.0
azure-common                             1.1.28
azure-core                               1.24.2
azure-cosmos                             4.3.0
azure-datalake-store                     0.0.52
azure-identity                           1.10.0
azure-keyvault-secrets                   4.4.0
azure-kusto-data                         0.0.45
azure-mgmt-containerinstance             1.5.0
azure-mgmt-core                          1.3.1
azure-mgmt-datafactory                   1.1.0
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg                3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store                0.5.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg                         3.0.2
azure-mgmt-resource                      21.1.0
azure-nspkg                              3.0.2
azure-servicebus                         7.8.0
azure-storage-blob                       12.8.1
azure-storage-common                     2.1.0
azure-storage-file                       2.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Document](https://www.codethebest.com/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-azure-solved/) it says,

> If it is python 3. xx, so I will use the pip3 command.

```
pip3 install azure
```

or

`pip install azure`

***References:***

- [Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62953789/getting-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-azure)
- [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63313040/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-azure)

Comment: "Starting with v5.0.0, the 'azure' meta-package is deprecated and cannot be installed anymore. Please install the service specific packages prefixed by `azure` needed for your application." -- https://pypi.org/project/azure/